# Python send emails one by one to multiple recipients

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

```
for email_to in EMAIL_TO:
    with smtplib.SMTP('wsmtp.ecounterp.com', 587) as smtp:
        try:
            smtp.starttls()
            smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)            
            #print(email_to)
            msg['To'] = email_to
            smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, email_to, msg.as_string())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I'm trying to send emails to multiple recipients and managed to send successfully.
However the issue is that the 'To' part of the sent email is, for example, like 'a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com'. So strange is that I've looped through the list('EMAIL_TO') but does not be sent one by one. What I was expecting is 'a@a.com' to a@a.com user, and 'b@b.com' to b@b.com user and so on. How do we do that? and what is the problem of my code?

I've tried to put time.sleep(30) in the loop. but still failed.
Is this a server-specific problem?

---

the value of EMAIL_TO is ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com']. and what I get  printed with print(email_to) is

```
a@a.com
b@b.com
c@c.com
```

Comment: I'd triple-check the value of `EMAIL_TO`. What gets printed with `print(email_to)`?

Comment: I'm trying to send the same email to multiple recipients but want to send one by one that they aren't aware other people have received the same email.

Comment: I've also tried the same with my gmail account for sending the same email to the same recipients but the result is also the same...